# Make buttons overlapped by a div clickable

Tags: html, css

I don't know what this effect is called, but this image will most defiantly ring a bell for you.

[image]

Can you see the tasks (the last item in the menu)? when you scrollup and the menu elements go down, they look like they are fading into the main div.

well, that screenshot is of what I have done so far using:

```
#mainMenu #menuList {
      width: inherit;
      min-width: 218px;
      margin: 65px 0 46px 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;
      overflow-y: auto;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      text-align: left;
   }

   #mainMenu #menuList:before {
      content: "";
      width: inherit;
      height: 40px;
      position: fixed; top: 60px;
      background: rgba(19,28,38,1);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,28,38,1) 0%, rgba(19,28,38,1) 5%, rgba(19,28,38,0) 100%);
      background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(19,28,38,1)), color-stop(5%, rgba(19,28,38,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(19,28,38,0)));
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,28,38,1) 0%, rgba(19,28,38,1) 5%, rgba(19,28,38,0) 100%);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,28,38,1) 0%, rgba(19,28,38,1) 5%, rgba(19,28,38,0) 100%);
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,28,38,1) 0%, rgba(19,28,38,1) 5%, rgba(19,28,38,0) 100%);
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(19,28,38,1) 0%, rgba(19,28,38,1) 5%, rgba(19,28,38,0) 100%);
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#131c26', endColorstr='#131c26', GradientType=0 );
   }

   #mainMenu #menuList:after {
      content: "";
      width: inherit;
      height: 40px;
      position: fixed; bottom: 45px;
      background: rgba(19,28,38,0);
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,28,38,0) 0%, rgba(19,28,38,1) 95%, rgba(19,28,38,1) 100%);
      background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(19,28,38,0)), color-stop(95%, rgba(19,28,38,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(19,28,38,1)));
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,28,38,0) 0%, rgba(19,28,38,1) 95%, rgba(19,28,38,1) 100%);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,28,38,0) 0%, rgba(19,28,38,1) 95%, rgba(19,28,38,1) 100%);
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(19,28,38,0) 0%, rgba(19,28,38,1) 95%, rgba(19,28,38,1) 100%);
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(19,28,38,0) 0%, rgba(19,28,38,1) 95%, rgba(19,28,38,1) 100%);
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#131c26', endColorstr='#131c26', GradientType=0 );
   }

      #mainMenu #menuList a {
         color: #596B80;
         display: block;
         padding: 8px 15px;
      }

      #mainMenu #menuList a:hover {
         color: #B3C3D5;
      }

      #mainMenu #menuList a.active,
      #mainMenu #menuList a.active:hover {
         color: #18BC9A;
      }
```

HTML

```
<div id="menuList">
      <a <?php href('index.php');?>><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i>Dashboard</a>
      <a <?php href('members.php');?>><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i>Members</a>
      <a <?php href('projects.php');?>><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i>Projects</a>
      <a <?php href('tasks.php');?>><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i>Tasks</a>
   </div>
```

The problem now however, as you most likely noticed I am using DIV with gradient and overlaying the div above the Main menu at the very bottom.

So now, I can't click on these buttons! how can I achieve the same results but make the buttons click-able?

Comment: pl provide jsfiddle link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign `pointer-events:none;` to the overlaying div so then it can be clicked through